# Join on Subquery: Google BigQuery

Tags: join, subquery, google-bigquery

I am trying to join two tables:

```
select * from
(select *, STRING(ID) as ID_string from Dataset1.Table1 where create_date >= 1388514600) as A left join each Dataset2.Table1 as B on A.ID_string = B.ID
```

On running the above query, I get the following error:

> Field 'ID_string' not found in table 'Dataset1.Table1'

Why is the join not recognizing the newly created column "ID_string"?

Comment: Can you try the same query, specifying each field with its name, instead of using *?

Comment: its working now, after specifying all column names. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Try the same query, but specifying each field by its name (instead of using *).